# Determining the goodness of an R fit using lm()

Tags: r, lm

I learned to get a linear fit with some points using lm in my R script. So, I did that (which worked nice), and printed out the fit:

```
lm(formula = y2 ~ x2)

Residuals:
         1          2          3          4 
 5.000e+00 -1.000e+01  5.000e+00  7.327e-15 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)   70.000     17.958   3.898  0.05996 . 
x2            85.000      3.873  21.947  0.00207 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 8.66 on 2 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.9959, Adjusted R-squared: 0.9938 
F-statistic: 481.7 on 1 and 2 DF,  p-value: 0.00207
```

I'm trying to determine the best way to judge how great this fit is. I need to compare this fit with a few others (which are also linear using `lm()` function). What value from this summary would be the best way to judge how good this fit is? I was thinking to use the residual standard error. Any suggestions. Also, how do I extract that value from the fit variable?

Comment: [This](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4510/how-to-compute-goodness-of-fit-for-a-linear-model-in-r) question over on stats.SE is essentially an exactly dup, although the accepted answer basically says to go read a statistics book.

Comment: but how do I get the values out of the fit variable?

Comment: Gee, I wonder if there's a problem with correlation here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access the pieces produced by `summary` directly, you can just call `summary` and store the result in a variable and then inspect the resulting object:

```
rs <- summary(lm1)
names(rs)
```

Perhaps `rs$sigma` is what you're looking for?

**EDIT**

Before someone chides me, I should point out that for some of this information, this is not the recommended way to access it. Rather you should use the designated extractors like `residuals()` or `coef`.

Comment: @reising1 - I believe so, yes. The primary recommended extractors are `coef`, `fitted` and `residuals`, I believe. Don't quote me on that being a complete list, though.

Answer (score 2):

This code would do something similar:

```
 y2 <- seq(1, 11, by=2)+rnorm(6)  # six data points to your four points
 x2=1:6
 lm(y2 ~ x2)
 summary(lm(y2 ~ x2))
```

The adjusted R^2 is the "goodness of fit" measure. It is saying that 99% of the variance in y2 can be "explained" by a straight line fit of y2 to x2. Whether you want to interpret your model with only 4 data points on the basis of that result is a matter of judgment. It would seem to somewhat dangerous to me.

To extract the residual sum of squares you use:

```
summary(lm(y2~x2))$sigma
```

See this for further details:

```
?summary.lm
```

Comment: I see how to print summary, but how do I get values out of the summary? I want to get the residual standard error.

Answer (score 1):

There are some nice regression diagnostic plots you can look at with

```
plot(YourRegression, which=1:6)
```

where which=1:6 give you all six plots. The RESET test and bptest will test for misspecification and heteroskedasticity:

```
resettest(...)
bptest(...)
```

There are a lot of resources out there to think about this sort of thing. [Fitting Distributions in R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Ricci-distributions-en.pdf)  is one of them, and Faraway's "Practical Regression and Anova" is an R classic. I basically learned econometrics in R from Farnsworth's paper/book, although I don't recall if he has anything about goodness of fit.

If you are going to do a lot of econometrics in R, [Applied Econometrics in R](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387773169) is a great pay-for book.  And I've used the [R for Economists](http://www.mayin.org/ajayshah/KB/R/R_for_economists.html) webpage a lot.

Those are the first ones that pop to mind. I will mull a little more.

Comment: but how do I get the values out of the fit variable? I want to get the residual standard error